# Finding the oldest and ending on specific user input

Tags: python

I have just started Python and I am attempting a simple exercise. It's to end a program on a user specified input and then finding the oldest age from a set of ages entered. I got the user input but having issues with the oldest age aspect. Where am I going wrong? I think I may not be 100% on the "None" aspect. Here is code below:

```py
largest = None

while True:
    name = str(input("What is your name? enter Yvonne to end program."))
    if name.strip() != 'Yvonne':
        age = int(input("Please enter your age"))
    elif name.strip() == 'Yvonne':
        if largest is None or largest < age:
            largest = age
        print("Oldest age is: ",  largest)
        break
```

The output I get is the wrong number being selected as the oldest:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve got your test for largest in the wrong place:

```py
largest = None

while True:
    name = str(input("What is your name? enter Yvonne to end program."))
    if name.strip() != 'Yvonne':
        age = int(input("Please enter your age"))
    
        if largest is None or largest < age:
            largest = age
    else:
        print("Oldest age is: ",  largest)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep practicing . Such a bad oversight on my part